# string to array arduino

Tags: arrays, arduino

I have specific problem with Manchester code for Arduino. The problem is that array is written as `man.transmitArray(16,data);`, where 16 bytes are send in one array, while data ("data" in this example) works only for this

**example:** `uint8_t data[16] = {0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0};` (this works, but I need something different).

I need data[16] that reads pressure and temperature from MS5611 sensor, and send it over OOK modulation with Manchester code.

*My question is:*
How to convert for example pressure given in format 1013.25 into data[6]? Later will expand this to data[4] for temperature, and the rest for ID number for specific transmitter. I am newbie in Arduino programming and any help will be appreciated. Or, data from sensor may be hexadecimal number, but problem is the same - how to convert say 8F331A into data[6]? On receiver side, it should be "decoded" back to hex number.

Thanks.

Comment: Here is code:
long getPressure()
{
  long D1, D2, dT, P;
  float TEMP;
  int64_t OFF, SENS;

  D1 = getData(0x48, 10);
  D2 = getData(0x50, 1);

  dT = D2 - ((long)calibrationData[5] << 8);
  TEMP = (2000 + (((int64_t)dT * (int64_t)calibrationData[6]) >> 23));//was /(float)100;
  OFF = ((unsigned long)calibrationData[2] << 16) + (((int64_t)calibrationData[4] * dT) >> 7);
  SENS = ((unsigned long)calibrationData[1] << 15) + (((int64_t)calibrationData[3] * dT) >> 8);
  P = (((D1 * SENS) >> 21) - OFF) >> 15;

  return TEMP; //hope this will works
  return P;
}
Can I make array from those data?

Comment: I wonder, does this code actually gives array?
  D1 = getData(0x48, 10);
  D2 = getData(0x50, 1);
Does D1 will give array of 10 numbers? and D1 of 1 number? Maybe I cand send it over Manchester code directly?

Comment: Let's narrow the problem. Tried next:  uint8_t dat1[10]=getData(0x48,10);
  uint8_t dat2[1]=getData(0x50,1); But, got error message: "array must be initialized with a brace-enclosed initializer". Is there some command that can solve it?

Comment: Okay, GOT IT! In square brackets, there should be not number of elements in array to work properly. Instead   uint8_t dat1[10]={getData(0x48,10)}; (which gives 10 zeroes), it should be:   uint8_t dat1[]={getData(0x48,10)}; Anyway, thank you very much.

Comment: Can you post that as an answer @Wildman? Your comment is practically unreadable, as code.